# Laravel - custom search

Tags: php, database, laravel, search, input

I made my custom search for my small car project and I have two problems now. Let me first show my code:
This is my `SearchController` :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Car;
use DB;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SearchController extends Controller
{

    // ovo je search controller


    public function index(){
        $cars = Car::all();
        return view('searchcreate')->with('cars', $cars);
    }

    public function blogs(Request $request){

        $from = $request->input('from');
        $to = $request->input('to');
        $search = $request->input('fuel');

        $cars = DB::table('cars')
                    ->where('brand', '=', $request->input('brand'))
                    ->where('model', '=', $request->input('model'))
                    ->where('fuel', '=', $request->input('fuel'))
                    ->where('gear', '=', $request->input('gear'))
                    ->whereBetween('price', [$from, $to])
                    ->get();

        return view('search')->with('cars', $cars);
    }
}
```

And this is my `search page`:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Search</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    {!! Form::open(['action' => 'SearchController@blogs', 'method' => 'GET']) !!}
                        <div class="column">
                            <label for="name">Brand:</label></br>
                                <select class="form-control" name="brand" id="input" onchange="random_function()">                                 
                                    <option value="" selected>Select your option</option>
                                    <option value="Volkswagen">Volkswagen</option>
                                    <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
                                    <option value="Audi">Audi</option>                                                                   
                                </select>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="column">
                            <label for="model">Model:</label></br>
                            <select class="form-control" id="output" name="model">

                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="column">
                            <label for="fuel">Fuel:</label></br>
                            <select class="form-control" name="fuel">
                                <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
                                <option value="diesel">Diesel</option>
                                <option value="gasoline">Gasoline</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
<br>
                        <div class="column">
                            <label for="gear">Gear:</label></br>
                            <input name="gear[]" type="checkbox" placeholder="" value="ABS">ABS
                            <input name="gear[]" type="checkbox" placeholder="" value="CL">Child lock
                            <input name="gear[]" type="checkbox" placeholder="" value="navigation">Navigation
                            <input name="gear[]" type="checkbox" placeholder="" value="isofix">Isofix
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="column">
                            <label for="from">Price from:</label></br>
                            <input name="from" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control" value="0">
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="column">
                            <label for="to">Price to:</label></br>
                            <input name="to" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control" value="150000">
                        </div>
                        <br>

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                            Search
                        </button>
                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

So my two problems are:

First problem is that all my search inputs are required, I need if user type just brand or just fuel to show him all cars with that specific brand or fuel.

Second problem is my `gear input`, it is an array that users select when creating car post. And right now if user want to search for some car with for example just ABS while searching user needs to check exactly gear that car post have. I need my search to find any car post with only checked gear, so no need to check exactly gear. 
What is solution to these two problems?

EDITED:
My `cars migration`:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCarsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('cars', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('brand');
            $table->string('model');
            $table->string('fuel');
            $table->string('gear');
            $table->string('price');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->dateTime('refresh');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('cars');
    }
}
```

My `CarsController`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Car;
use DB;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class CarsController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['index', 'show']]);
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $cars = Car::orderBy('refresh', 'desc')->get();
        return view('cars.index')->with('cars', $cars);    
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('cars.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'brand' => 'required',
            'model' => 'required',
            'fuel' => 'required',
            'gear' => 'required',
            'price' => 'required'
        ]);

        $car = new Car;
        $car->brand = $request->input('brand');
        $car->model = $request->input('model');
        $car->fuel = $request->input('fuel');
        $car->gear = implode(',', $request->input('gear'));
        $car->price = $request->input('price');
        $car->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $car->refresh = Carbon::now();
        $car->save();

        return redirect('/cars');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $car = Car::find($id);
        return view('cars.show')->with('car', $car);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $car = Car::find($id);
        return view('cars.edit')->with('car', $car);
    }


    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'brand' => 'required',
            'model' => 'required',
            'fuel' => 'required',
            'gear' => 'required',
            'price' => 'required'
        ]);

        $car = Car::find($id);
        $car->brand = $request->input('brand');
        $car->model = $request->input('model');
        $car->fuel = $request->input('fuel');
        $car->gear = implode(',', $request->input('gear'));
        $car->price = $request->input('price');
        $car->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $car->save();

        return redirect('/cars');

    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $car = Car::find($id);
        $car->delete();
        return redirect('/cars');
    }
```

And my `create.blade.php` for cars table:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Create car post
                </div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    {!! Form::open(['action' => 'CarsController@store', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
                        <div class="column">
                            <label for="brand">Brand:</label></br>
                            <select class="form-control" id="input" name="brand" onchange="random_function()">
                                <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
                                <option value="Volkswagen">Volkswagen</option>
                                <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
                                <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="column">
                            <label for="model">Model:</label></br>
                            <select class="form-control" id="output" name="model">

                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="column">
                            <label for="fuel">Fuel:</label></br>
                            <select class="form-control" name="fuel">
                                <option value="diesel">Diesel</option>
                                <option value="gasoline">Gasoline</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="column">
                            <label for="gear">Gear:</label></br>
                            <input name="gear[]" type="checkbox" placeholder="" value="ABS">ABS
                            <input name="gear[]" type="checkbox" placeholder="" value="CL">Child lock
                            <input name="gear[]" type="checkbox" placeholder="" value="navigation">Navigation
                            <input name="gear[]" type="checkbox" placeholder="" value="isofix">Isofix
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="column">
                            <label for="price">Price:</label></br>
                            <input name="price" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <br><br>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                            Submit
                        </button>
                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: What column type is gear, since it is a multiple selection option?

Comment: @mrhn It is varchar

Comment: So it is only the search input that is an array?

Comment: We're here bcs we want to help, but SO isn't a code-writing service ... what have you tried?

Comment: @yes, search input array and ```store function``` that is with ```implode```

Answer (score 1):

You should split your query up into the individual search parts, as there are 3 different types of where clause that you need - standard `where`, `whereIn` (for the gears array) and `whereBetween` (if a price is set)

This should work:

```
$carQuery = DB::table('cars');

// standard where fields
foreach ($request->only(['brand', 'model', 'fuel']) as $term => $value) {
    if (empty($value)) {
        continue;
    }
    $carQuery->where($term, $value);
}

// gear is one of gears array values
if ($gears = $request->get('gear')) {
    $carQuery->whereIn('gear', $gears);
}

// between a price from/to the values set
if (
    $from = $request->input('from')
    && $to = $request->input('to')
) {
    $carQuery->whereBetween('price', [$from, $to]);
}

$cars = $carQuery->get();
```

Comment: Sir now it is working all fine if I just select brand and model, or if I just select price from - to. But with gears it still doesn't show anything if I just select one checkbox.. Please help

Comment: So with cars that have more than just one gear selected it doesn't show anything, it just show cars with one gear selected, and I need to show me all cars if my gear selected input for SEARCH

Comment: My ```$car->gear``` is multiple selection , ```array```. Maybe it is something about that ?

Comment: And I have a small error with price, it shows me all cars no matter what price did I type in ```$from``` and ```$to``` input

Comment: What does your cars table data look like?

Comment: Sir I edited my question so you can see my ```cars table```, ```CarsController``` and ```create.blade.php```